# I have to determine from a string the starting and arrival cities

Tags: java, string, input, split, output

I have the following code which, by means of a keyboard input, gives me the start and arrival .. the start is determined according to the "da" proposition, while the arrival determines it according to the preposition "a" so I'm fighting now is: I want to get the start and the arrival even if I change the order of the propositions .. you know how I could proceed .. 
    this is the OUTPUT I get :

```
    I want to go from ostuni to trapani

    Partenza :ostuni 

    Arrivo :trapani

    but if I wrote like this:

    I want to go to ostuni by trapani

    I would like to print the same start and finish correctly ..that is

    Patenza :trapani

    Arrivo :ostuni

    Is this processing possible?

thanks a lot for the attention! Good day
```

package eubot.controller;

```
import eubot.intent.Intent;

public class EubotEngine {
    public Intent getIntent(String stringInput) {
     String str1 = "";
     String str2 = "";
     Intent dictionary = null;


     for (String str3 : Intent.keyWord) {
     if (stringInput.contains(str3)) {

     //System.out.println("La stringa contiene : " + str3);
     int indice1 = stringInput.indexOf(str3) + str3.length();
     String splittable =
     stringInput.substring(indice1,stringInput.length()).trim();
     String splittable2[] = splittable.split(" ");
     int index = 0;
     for (String str : splittable2) {
     str = splittable2[index +1];
     str1 = str;
     System.out.println("Partenza :" + str1);
     break;
     }
     String splittable3[] = splittable.split(" ");
     for(String str : splittable3) {
     str = splittable3[index + 3];
     str2 = str;
     System.out.println("Arrivo :" + str2);
     break;
     }
     index++;
     dictionary = new Intent();
     dictionary.setTesto(stringInput);
     }
     }
     return dictionary;
     }
}

package eustema.eubot.intent;

public class Intent {

    public String testo;

    public String getTesto() {
        return testo;
    }

    public void setTesto(String testo) {
        this.testo = testo;
    }

    public static String[] keyWord = { "devo andare", "voglio andare", "vorrei andare", "devo recarmi"};

    public static String[] parameter = { "bari", "roma", "milano","pisa","firenze","napoli","como","torino" };
}
package eustema.eubot.main;

import java.util.Scanner;

import eustema.eubot.controller.*;
import eustema.eubot.intent.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("<<-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|<<<BENVENUTO IN EuBoT>>>|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|->>");
        EubotEngine controller = new EubotEngine();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String string;
        while (true) {
            string = input.nextLine();
            Intent intent = controller.getIntent(string);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47033932/i-want-to-have-the-second-part-of-the-string-or-the-last-part-of-the-sentence-ho

Answer (score 0):

I know this will not be considered a good answer:)

This is non-trivial to solve by means of imperative programming. The reason is there are many forms in which one can express the same intent. Things like filler words, synonyms, inversions and in general things you did not think about could disrupt your algorithm.

Of course it depends on the level of accuracy you want to achieve. If you are happy that this will not work for all cases, you could always put in conditions like:

```
if (arr[index-1] == "from") setStart(arr[index]);
if (arr[index-1] == "to") setDestination(arr[index]);
```

Google, Amazon and Apple are battling to improve this sort of human-computer interaction, but they are using a more mathematical/statistical approach through machine learning.

So, if you're looking for state of the art:

- Main search terms: context-free grammars.
- Other key words: Markov models, Information extraction, vector space models, tf-idf

Comment: Thanks for the attention you gave to my question .. I did not know this issue .. anyway your suggestion will definitely come back to me..this is certain .. regarding the program I'm making .. i would like to be able to get a Mechanism as automated .. I have to document better .. Thanks a lot for the answer :)